# Change the length of a variable in IMPALA SQL Select statement through SAS

Tags: sas, impala, proc-sql

I am connecting to an impala server to retrieve some data.
However I want to change the length of the variable in the impala pass-through sql statement because otherwise it will retrieve the variable with a length of 32767 which is not optimized.

This is how I would do it in SAS:

```
proc sql;
    connect to impala (dsn="somedsn");
    create table want as
    select * 
    from connection to impala
        (select var1 length=50  
            from &disc_table.);
    disconnect from impala;
quit;
```

However, as IMPALA does not have the same sql statement structure, it does not work.

What is the correct statement to retrieve the `var1` with a `length=50` in IMPALA SQL  statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to change the length in the SAS-side `select`:

```
proc sql;
    connect to impala (dsn="somedsn");
    create table want as
    select var1 length=50 
    from connection to impala
        (select var1 
            from &disc_table.);
    disconnect from impala;
quit;
```

You could also use the `DBMAX_TEXT` option I believe in the connection step, though I'm not familiar with Impala's options specifically.

---

Given the comments below, it looks like the problem is that Impala doesn't support CHAR/VARCHAR, and so you get 32767 length strings.  Your solution might be to do both things Tom and I suggest, ie:

```
proc sql;
    connect to impala (dsn="somedsn");
    create table want as
    select var1 length=50 
    from connection to impala
        (select cast(var1 as varchar(50)) as var1 
           from &disc_table.);
    disconnect from impala;
quit;
```

Which might mean you get less data transferred back AND you get a smaller column; or you might add DBMAX_TEXT here; or you can also do as the [kb article suggests](https://support.sas.com/kb/53/835.html) and additionally add a limit in the ODBC connection options.

Another option is to use [SAS DS2](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=ds2ref&docsetTarget=n1vzzs6f1zx6a6n1c10tihbwx6xu.htm&locale=en), though it looks like it still has the same issue ultimately (in that older versions of Impala don't support varchar/char).  That document suggests upgrading to CDH 5.2 (which I think is a Cloudera implementation of Impala).  I'm not sure if non-Cloudera versions support VARCHAR, though there are at least some mentions in the [Impala change notes](https://impala.apache.org/docs/changelog-3.4.html) for version 3.4, specifically [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-5092) which mentions adding it to Kudu tables.

Comment: Yeah that's how I used it. However I want to put it in the SQL pass-through statement so that the data I download from Impala would be smaller. Will have a look at the `DBMAX_TEXT` option. Thanks.

Comment: Does the combination of Tom's answer and mine solve it?  SAS may be allocating 32767 for it, but Impala may be only doing 50 on its side if you use `cast`.

Comment: No. I think it's just that this is pretty bad (cf.https://support.sas.com/kb/53/835.html)

Comment: Added this plus some other details in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask IMPALA to CAST the variable to one with the correct length.

```
... (select cast(var1 as varchar(50)) as var1 from &disc_table.) ...
```

Comment: The length is still 32767 using `(select cast(var1 as varchar(50)) as var1 from &disc_table.)`